# Elastic trace generation using gem5 does not give results as said in the webpage

Tags: gem5

Hello I am using the instructions given in the following web page to try and get some traces for instruction and data:
https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/cpu_models/TraceCPU

The traces generated doesnot seem to have "time stamps" as mentioned in the program and all of the operation seems to be just 'r. Also bot the traces generated could be opened with *decode_packet_trace.py*, which I thought would open the data trace alone. While trying to decode the traces using *decode_inst_dep_trace.py*, I getthe following error:

> Did not find proto definition, attempting to generate
>   src/proto: warning: directory does not exist.
>   src/proto/inst_dep_record.proto: No such file or directory
>   Failed to import proto definitions<

Why is this ? Am I doing this right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the installation instructions given in the link above, and decided to explore the utility scripts provided; the issue was that the program was assuming the location from which it was being executed is the root file for Gem5; which it wasnt; I gave the necessary files their full path in the script and it worked. I am no longer getting the error, the issue is resolved and I am able to get good, readable traces.

Question still remains why do we have two utility programs, when decode_inst_trace.py or decode_inst_dep_trace.py seems to produce excellent and well readable ASCII interpretations of the traces.